# Pandas dataframe split or groupby dataframe at each occurence of value (True) in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

a have a df like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'words':['hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'sentence', 'this', 'is', 'another', 'sentence'], 'indicator':[1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]})
```

which gives me:

```
    words  indicator
0        hi          1
1      this          0
2        is          0
3         a          0
4  sentence          0
5      this          1
6        is          0
7   another          0
8  sentence          0
```

Now I want to merge all values of column 'words', that follow the '1' in indicator until the next '1' comes up.
Something like this would be the ideal result:

```
                      words  indicator  counter
0     hi this is a sentence          1        5
1  this is another sentence          1        4
```

It's not that easy to explain, that's why I rely on this example.
I tried groupby and split, but couldn't get to a solution.
Last try would be to set up some kind of df.iterrows(), but I want to avoid this for now since the actual df is quite large.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the [cumulative sum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumsum.html) of your indicator, then groupby that to join all the words together on a space and count the number of words in each sentence.

```py
df["indicator"] = df["indicator"].cumsum()
df = df.groupby(
    "indicator", as_index=False
).agg(
    words=("words", " ".join), 
    counter=("indicator", "size")
)
#    indicator                     words  counter
# 0          1     hi this is a sentence        5
# 1          2  this is another sentence        4
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
Performing a cumulative sum was new for me, that did the trick.

Comment: I've just updated my answer as I realised you can get the size and join the words all in a single groupby operation. Let me know if any of it doesn't make sense